# Issue when copying one array into another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I am trying to put the contents of an array into another. I have this json ($scopeProducts)...

```
{
"ID": "...",
"Groups": [
    {
        "Products": []
    }
{
        "Other": []
    }
]
}
```

And I am trying to add the following json into the 'Products' array ($scope.selectedProducts)...

```
[
{
    "ProductCode": "Code1",
},
{
    "ProductCode": "Code1",
},
]
```

and I end up getting this...

```
{
"ID": "...",
"Groups": [
    {
        "Products": 
    [
        [
            {
                "ProductCode": "Code1",
            },
            {
                "ProductCode": "Code1",
            },
        ]
    ]
    }
{
        "Other": []
    }
]
}
```

... which is wrong (check the double [[ in the products array). I am using the javascript push function...

```
$scopeProducts.Groups[0].Products.push($scope.selectedProducts);
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this correctly without creating the double array [[]] ? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pushing an array into another array as an *entry*, not appending the entries to it.

If you want to append it (barring Angular having some utility function):

```
$scopeProducts.Groups[0].Products.push.apply($scopeProducts.Groups[0].Products, $scope.selectedProducts);
```

That's a bit tricky: It uses `Function#apply` to call `push` with multiple arguments, one for each entry in `$scope.selectedProducts`. This is because JavaScript arrays don't have a native `append` method; the closest they come is `concat`, which creates a *new* array. But the above works for append functionality.